# Creating Glass - What am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, glass

I've followed all the tutorials, tried so many different things. But changing the transmission to 1 just makes the shape go grey. I've turned on refraction in the light settings and nothing has changed.

[image: What am i doing wrong here?]

Comment: You are wanting to know how to do glass in Evee?

Comment: Maybe it's grey because there is nothing to reflect. Try the same setting in 'look dev'

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn on the **Screen Space Refraction** both in the **Render** panel

[image]

and in the **Material** settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I generally use a **Glass Shader** and a **Transparent Shader**. Then use a **Mix Shader** to join them before giving the **Material Output**.

[image]

Comment: The transparent shader reduces the realism of the scene: it should be used only for windows or large objects to reduce the noise in the scene, and always combined with the ***Light Path** node